# Array of Objects, como iterar y devolver array solo con object indicados!

Tags: javascript, array, bucles, objeto, function

Estoy aprendiendo JS básico y el ejercicio me pide que teniendo un array de objetos lo itere y si dicho objeto incluye un valor, eliminarlo. Todo debe estar envuelto y trabajado dentro de una función, la función debe devolver un array con los objetos indicados.

Aquí dejo el input y el output con lo que debe devolver:

Input:

```
[
  { type: 'pineapple', size: 'M'},
  { type: 'pepperoni', size: 'S'},
  { type: 'pineapple', size: 'S'},
  { type: 'mushrooms', size: 'L'}
]
```

Output:

```
[   { type: 'pepperoni', size: 'S'}, { type: 'mushrooms', size: 'L'}  ]
```

Al iterar la función debe devolver el array de objetos con únicamente los objetos que no contengan 'pineapple' .

Agradecería vuestra ayuda ya que no se ni por donde empezar!!!!

Gracias de antemano!

Lo que yo intenté fué esto, estoy cerca pero aún me falta eliminar los objetos que contenga pineapple

```
           function filterPizzas(pizzas) {
             let pizzaNoPineapple = [];
              for( let pizza in pizzas){
                 if(pizzas[0].type === 'pineapple'){
                 pizzaNoPineapple.push(pizzas);
    }
   }
    return pizzas;
  }
```

Comment: hay una function llamada filter() puedes usarla por medio de un lambda para condicionarlo a retornar por medio de la llave que necesites [].filter(x=> x.tullave != 'tupalabra')

Comment: David, qué has intentado? Por favor comparte el código. Puede que estés muy cerca de la solución

Comment: Lo que intenté hacer fue recorrer el array de objetos y posteriormente eliminar y guardarlo en otra variable... creo que no estoy haciendo nada bien, los metodos que debo usar son de JS Básico ya que estoy haciendo un precurso para entrar en un bootcamp, gracias de antemano

Comment: También intente esto:  function filterPizzas(pizzas) {
  let pizzaNoPineapple = [];
  for( let pizza in pizzas){
    if(pizzas[0].type === 'pineapple'){
      pizzaNoPineapple.push(pizzas);
    }
  }
  return pizzas;
}

Comment: David, tu intento debe ir en la pregunta y no en los comentarios. Haz clic en [edit] y agrega lo que haga falta a la pregunta. Saludos

Comment: perdón, es la primera vez que utilizo stack overflow, siento el error, ya esta arreglado y gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Al cambiar eso tampoco funciona ya que me tiene que devolver un array solamente con los objetos que no contengan pineapple...He tratado de almacenarlo en otra variable para cuando muestre en pantalla pizzas no aparezcan ya que se movieron a esa nueva variable, pero no funciona, gracias por vuestra ayuda de nuevo.

Comment: ah, otro error que tenes es que, segun entiendo, vos queres guardar en el nuevo array, las pizzas que no tengan piña. Tendrias que reemplazar ``if(pizzas[0].type === 'pineapple')`` por ``if(pizza.type !== 'pineapple')``

Comment: Lo que realmente quiero hacer es eliminar directamente las pizzas que contenga piña, para cuando me devuelva el valor de array de objetos tan solo aparezcan las pizzas que no tienen piña.

Comment: @DavidPardomartin tambien tenes mal el return, estas devolviendo el mismo objeto que recibis. Deberia ser ``return pizzaNoPineapple``

Comment: los fallos que me estás comentando ya los probé anteriormente y tampoco resuelvo el ejercicio, yo tan solo quiero iterar sobre ese array de objetos y eliminar el objeto que contenga piña..... para asi cuando me devuelva el valor solo devuelva el array de objetos con las pizzas sin piña... creo que es algo sencillo solo que no logro aclarar mis ideas, a ver si pudieras aclararme sin llegar a decirme la respuesta para yo conseguir dar con el resultado, Gracias

Comment: Perdon, cada vez que veia un error te lo marcaba y no habia visto que tenias 4 en total. Ademas te pase mal ``pizza.type``, era ``pizzas[pizza].type``. Ya esta todo corregido y funcionando en la respuesta.

Comment: nada no te preocupes, tu respuesta me ha servido de gran ayuda, estoy eternamente agradecido!!!! Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tene varios errores pero esta bien enfocada tu idea.

- Te falta cambiar 0 por el indice dinamico en la comparación
- La comparacion debe guardar los distintos, no los iguales
- Luego debes pushear el item `pizzas[pizza]`, no el objeto que recibis como parametro
- Finalmente en el return, tenes que devolver el array `pizzaNoPineapple` y estas devolviendo lo que recibis por parámetro, por eso nunca vas a ver un cambio.

```js
const pizzas = [
  { type: 'pineapple', size: 'M'},
  { type: 'pepperoni', size: 'S'},
  { type: 'pineapple', size: 'S'},
  { type: 'mushrooms', size: 'L'}
]

function filterPizzas(pizzas) {
   let pizzaNoPineapple = [];
   for( let pizza in pizzas){
     if(pizzas[pizza].type !== 'pineapple'){
        pizzaNoPineapple.push(pizzas[pizza]);
     }
   }
   return pizzaNoPineapple;
}

console.log(filterPizzas(pizzas))
```

**TAMBIEN PODES HACERLO DE ESTA MANERA**

Podes hacer uso del método filter https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter, y el resultado queda mas lindo.

El método filter itera sobre cada elemento del array, aplicando una funcion que se pasa entre los parentesis del metodo: `array.filter(funcion)`.

En este caso el array es `pizzas`, llamamos al método filter y le pasamos una funcion en los parentesis. A cada elemento del array lo llamamos `pizza`, y es lo viaja como parametro de la funcion.

**Si no entendes a que le estoy llamando funcion, te hago una breve explicacion**

-------- inicio breve explicacion -------

> `pizza => pizza.type !== 'pineapple'` esto es una funcion en javascript, solo que se pueden escribir asi porque son de una sola linea. En este caso `pizza` es el parametro, y lo que va despues de la flecha es el return.
> Es lo mismo que hacer

```
 function nombreDeLaFuncion(pizz){
    let comparacion = pizza.type !== 'pineapple';
    return comparacion;
 }
```

Solo que en una linea queda mucho mas facil de leer

----------------- fin breve explicacion -----------

Continuando con la respuesta:

Esta funcion va a retornar todos los objetos que coincidan con la condicion dada, y los va a guardar en un nuevo array.

En este caso la funcion filter va a recorrer cada uno de los elementos, y los llamara `pizza`. En cada iteracion verá si `pizza.type !== 'pineapple` y los objetos `pizza` que arrojen `true` seran guardados en un nuevo array. A este array no lo guardamos en ningun lado, simplemente lo retornamos desde la funcion.

```js
    const pizzas = [
      { type: 'pineapple', size: 'M'},
      { type: 'pepperoni', size: 'S'},
      { type: 'pineapple', size: 'S'},
      { type: 'mushrooms', size: 'L'}
    ]

    function filterPizzas(pizzas) {
      return pizzas.filter(pizza => pizza.type !== 'pineapple')
    }

    console.log(filterPizzas(pizzas))
```

Comment: Realmente estoy eternamente agradecido a tu ayuda, ya me funciona si que es cierto que tenia varios fallos pero iba bien encaminado, ahora mi otra pregunta es...¿porque en la condicional pusiste if(pizzas[pizza].type? no me queda muy claro!!!!

Comment: porque la variable ``pizza`` devulve un numero de indice, es decir, la posicion del objeto dentro del array ``pizzas``. Entonces es lo mismo que hacer en la primer iteracion ``pizzas[0]...`` y en la segunda iteracion ``pizzas[1]...`` etc. Tené en cuenta que ``for...in`` no se recomienda usar para recorrer arrays, pero podes hacerlo https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: que método me recomiendas para iterar en arrays de objetos y despues modificarlos? Gracias

Comment: @DavidPardomartin te recomiendo usar ``filter`` como te dijeron en el primer comentario. Fijate que ya edite la respuesta con ``filter`` y agregué una explicación.

Comment: @DavidPardomartin si tu problema fue resuelto marca la respuesta como aceptada en valoración por la ayuda recibida

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta Agustin G. ya acepte tu respuesta ya que me sirvió de gran ayuda, gracias de nuevo, un saludo!